# FreeSwitch - using mod_xml_curl for Configuration acl list

Tags: php, xml, freeswitch

I am using mod_xml_curl to generate ACL list dynamically. I write a python script which create a XML file like acl.conf.xml except with custom IP from database. Then I write a PHP script to serve this file to freeswitch with mod_xml_curl.

Then in xml_curl.conf.xml file I added below lines.

```
<binding name="configuration">
  <param name="gateway-url" value="http://127.0.0.1:80/xml_handler.php" bindings="configuration"/>

</binding>
```

After that I restart the freeswitch server. But nothing happens. I also make xml_curl debug_on. But I cant find the problem. Does any one knows which part is wrong or missing in this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was loading XML file in wrong format in browser. I return an array instead of and XML format. When I fix that and restart freeswitch service, it works fine